# Datastax dsetool Solr create_core fail for TIMEUUID

Tags: solr, datastax-enterprise, datastax

Running Datastax tools on `DataStax Enterprise Server 4.6.0`
  to generate Solr from scratch from an existing table

```
dsetool create_core ks.table generateResources=true distributed=true reindex=true
```

Got

```
org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer$RemoteSolrException: 

    Type org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.ReversedType(org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.TimeUUIDType) 

is not supported with automatic Solr schema generation.
```

According to this http://www.datastax.com/documentation/datastax_enterprise/4.5/datastax_enterprise/srch/srchSolrType.html, Solr supports uuid and timeuuid as of 4.5

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Solr doesn't recognize timeuuid by default, we need to create the schema.xml file manually looks something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<schema name="autoSolrSchema" version="1.5">
<types>
<fieldType class="org.apache.solr.schema.StrField" name="StrField"/>
<fieldType class="org.apache.solr.schema.UUIDField" name="UUIDField"/>
<fieldType class="org.apache.solr.schema.TextField" name="TextField">
<analyzer>
<tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
<filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>
</fieldType>
<fieldType class="org.apache.solr.schema.TrieFloatField" name="TrieFloatField"/>
</types>
<fields>
<field indexed="true" multiValued="false" name="article_url" stored="true" type="StrField"/>
<field indexed="true" multiValued="false" name="articleid" stored="true" type="UUIDField"/>
<field indexed="true" multiValued="false" name="article_title" stored="true" type="StrField"/>
<field indexed="true" multiValued="false" name="image" stored="true" type="StrField"/>
<field indexed="true" multiValued="false" name="history" stored="true" type="UUIDField"/>
</fields>
<uniqueKey>(articleid)</uniqueKey>
</schema>
```

And define the `timeuuid` field as `UUIDField` , see `history`

then run

`dsetool create_core kular.articles schema=/home/ubuntu/articles_schema.xml generateResources=true distributed=true reindex=true`

Comment: FYI, this is only an issue when you have a timeuuid clustering column with clustering order by DESC. Should be addressed in a future version.